# ExcelマクロからPythonスクリプトが実行できない

Tags: python, vba, excel

下記に示すコードでExcelのデータをランダムフォレストを用いて解析しようとしたらExcelマクロの方で下記のようなエラーが発生してしまいました。

恐らくDataFilePathが上手く取得できていないものと考えられますが、定義の部分で絶対パスを定義してみたりしたのですが、実行できません。
何か対処法ご存じの方いらっしゃたらご助言お願い致します。

#### 現状のソースコード

Excelマクロ

```vb
Sub RandomForest()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler ' エラーハンドリングを設定
    
    Dim PythonPath As String
    Dim PythonScript As String
    Dim DataRange As Range
    Dim OutputRange As Range
    Dim DataFilePath As String
    Dim OutputFilePath As String
    Dim OutputFileDirectory As String
    
    ' Pythonのパスを指定
    PythonPath = "C:\Users\katou\anaconda4\python.exe"
    
    ' Pythonスクリプトのパスを指定
    PythonScript = "\RadomForest.py"
    
    ' データの範囲を指定
    On Error Resume Next ' エラーが発生した場合は次の行に進む
    Set DataRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B3:K5,P3:P5")
    On Error GoTo 0 ' エラーハンドリングを元に戻す
    
    If DataRange Is Nothing Then ' データの範囲が取得できなかった場合はエラーメッセージを表示
        MsgBox "データの範囲を指定できませんでした。", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' 出力先の範囲を指定
    Set OutputRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("S3")
    
    ' データファイルのパスを設定
    DataFilePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\data.csv"
    
    ' データを一時的なCSVファイルに保存
    DataRange.Copy
    With CreateObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
        .SetText .GetFromClipboard()
        .PutInFile DataFilePath
    End With
    ' Pythonスクリプトを実行
    Shell PythonPath & " " & PythonScript & " " & DataFilePath & " " & OutputFilePath, vbNormalFocus
    
    ' 出力ファイルのディレクトリパスを取得
    OutputFileDirectory = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    
    OutputFilePath = OutputFileDirectory & "output.csv"
    
    ' 出力結果を読み込んでExcelに貼り付け
    On Error Resume Next ' エラーが発生した場合は次の行に進む
    With Application.Workbooks.Open(OutputFilePath)
        .Sheets(1).UsedRange.Copy OutputRange
        .Close False
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0 ' エラーハンドリングを元に戻す
    
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then ' 出力ファイルの読み込みに失敗した場合はエラーメッセージを表示
        MsgBox "出力ファイルの読み込みに失敗しました。", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Kill DataFilePath
    Kill OutputFilePath
    Exit Sub ' 正常終了時はここで終了する
    
ErrorHandler: ' エラーハンドリング用のラベル
    MsgBox "エラーが発生しました: " & Err.Description, vbCritical
End Sub
```

Pythonスクリプト

```py
import sys
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectFromModel

# コマンドライン引数から入力ファイルパスと出力ファイルパスを取得
input_file = sys.argv[1]
output_file = sys.argv[2]

# データを読み込む
data = pd.read_csv(input_file)

# 目的パラメータ（y）を指定
y = data['P3':'P5']

# 説明変数（x）を指定
X = data.loc[2:4, 'B':'K']

# ランダムフォレストモデルを学習
model = RandomForestClassifier()
model.fit(X, y)

# 特徴量の重要度を取得
importances = model.feature_importances_

# 特徴量抽出を行う
selector = SelectFromModel(model, threshold=0.1)
selector.fit(X, y)
X_selected = selector.transform(X)

# 結果をCSVファイルに保存
result = pd.DataFrame({'importance': importances})
result.to_csv(output_file, index=False)
```

Comment: 「エラーが発生したのは、Excelのマクロの27行目である.PutInFile DataFilePath」と書かれた内容に依ると「Pythonスクリプトが実行できない」のではなく「Pythonスクリプトに渡すためのCSVファイルが作成できない」ように見えます。状況を正確に把握して、エラーメッセージも略さず表示されたままをテキストで提示してください。こちらのヘルプ記事を参考に。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), [スクショしたコードで質問して良いですか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3765)

Comment: 「Excelのマクロの方でエラーが発生してしまいました。」とありますが、どのようなエラーが発生したのでしょうか？ また、コードが読みにくいので整形していただけないでしょうか？（それぞれ(VBA, Python)のコード全体をマークダウンで記入してください）

Comment: 皆さん、ご指摘ありがとうございます。エラー表記を出すために少しコードを変えました。上記にエラーメッセージの画像を添付させて頂きました。確認していただけると嬉しいです。

Comment: `PutInFile`というメソッドは[MSForms.DataObject](https://www.odin.hyork.net/write/write0323.html)には存在しない[メソッド (Microsoft Forms)](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/methods-microsoft-forms)なので、それが問題では？ データを基に新しいシートを作成して [VBAで二次元配列のデータを高速にセルへ貼り付ける](https://vbabeginner.net/paste-2d-array-data-into-cells-at-high-speed/), [二次元配列をシートに反映する処理をパーツ化...](https://vba-create.jp/vba-array-arr-to-sheet/) それをファイルとして保存 [シートを別ブックとして保存する](http://officetanaka.net/excel/vba/tips/tips170.htm), [...シートを別ブックに保存する...](https://daitaideit.com/vba-sheet-copy-saveas/) すれば良いと思われます。